number of zeros of a power series defined by an absolutely convergent sequence
Let $a = (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an absolutely convergent sequence such that each $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, and define
$f_a(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n x^n$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. To avoid a trivial case, assume $f_a \ne 0$. I would like to know, if I have any $[a,b] \subseteq (-1,1)$, whether the number of zeros of $f_a$ on $[a,b]$ is finite.
I think this is true, and my thought is the following:
Let $[a,b] \subseteq (-1,1)$ be given. For any $x$ such that $|x|<1$, we have $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |a_n| |x|^n \le \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |a_n| < \infty$ by assumption, therefore the radius of convergence of $f_a$ is at least $1$. That is, $f_a(x)$ is an analytic on $[a,b]$. And since the number of zeros of an analytic function on a compact interval cannot be infinite, the claim should be true.
Is this correct, or is there any flaw in this logic? Any input would be appreciated!
